# how to learn the primefaces javascript API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

While learning JSF-2.2 with PrimeFaces 5.3 I came across javascript events handlers like the one used with `onComplete` attribute:

```
function handelSmptmSaveRequest(xhr, status, args) {
                            if (args.validationFailed) {
                                PF('smptmDlgWv').jq.effect("shake", {
                                    times : 5
                                }, 100);
                            } else {
                                PF('smptmDlgWv').hide();
                            }
                        }
```

I have multiple questions here:

1. What are the input variable `xhr, status, args` and where are they defined, and where do they get their values from?
2. <strike>Is this the only handler I need to use with jsf components events such as `onBlur` or `onClick`, and how can I learn them?</strike>
3. Is there any documentation for this? I came from Java SE where every thing is documented and explained, where to look for javascript documentations and how?

**Edit1**
This appears to be Ajax callbacks defined by PrimeFaces, and They're announced here http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=830 but there is still a problem, though the PF showcase has some examples of usage, but I can't fine do documentation for these functions, I'm adding ajax tag for the question.

Comment: Please, one question per question. And regarding 1 (and 3): start by searching the PrimeFaces documentation for 'xhr'...

Comment: @Kukeltje I found no documentation for this, maybe I'm not searching the right way, I hope some one with experience can show me the way.

Comment: It is worth starting with [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) as PrimeFaces utilizes jQuery UI under the hood.

Comment: This might answer some of your questions: http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/

Comment: There can be simply no documentation for this API if it is mostly used as internal. In this case parameter values and meaning can be figured out by debugging. You put a breakpoint inside the function and go up the stack trace to the origins of the call. At least this is how I would approach the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the [PrimeFaces 5.3 documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf), in PDF form.  (Here are docs for [all versions.](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation))

[Page 536](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#page=536) documents the parameters for the `oncomplete(xhr, status, args)` function:

> Javascript callback to process when ajax request completes. Takes
>   three arguments, xmlhttprequest, status string and optional arguments
>   provided by RequestContext API.

`XMLHttpRequest` is the [vanilla JS Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) that we all know and love.

`RequestContext` is defined on [page 588](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf#page=588) of the PrimeFaces 5.3 documentation:

> RequestContext is a simple utility that provides useful goodies such
>   as adding parameters to ajax callback functions. RequestContext is
>   available in both ajax and non-ajax requests.